# Angular - Get parent component receive data after init

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have Angular front end which fetches data from Lumen backend:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

    merge()
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.exampleDatabase!.getRepoIssues(this.itemId);
        }),
        map(data => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.isRateLimitReached = false;

          return data;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.isRateLimitReached = true;
          return observableOf([]);
        })
      ).subscribe(
      data => this.applyDataChanges(data)
    );
  }

  private applyDataChanges(data: any) {
    let tree = [];

    for(let b of data.buildings) {
      let children = [];
      for(let c of b.buildings){
        children.push(new ChecklistNodeModel(c.name, false))
      }
      tree.push(new ChecklistNodeModel(b.group.name, false, children));
    }

    this.TREE_DATA = tree;

    this.itemId > 0 ?
      this.form = data as ControllingCompanyNewsModel :
      this.form = new ControllingCompanyNewsModel(0,null,'','','', data.buildings);
  }
```

Parent component has following property which then passes through @Input binding to child component:

```
  <app-checklist-tree [treeData]="TREE_DATA"></app-checklist-tree>
```

and

```
  @Input() treeData = [];
```

The question is for sone reason the child component has empty `treeData` property. While parent component has property updated correctly.

Could anyone advice where I made a mistake?
Thank you!

Adding child component code

```
export class ChecklistTreeComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() treeData = [];
  @Output() treeDataChange = new EventEmitter<ChecklistNodeModel[]>();
  levels = new Map<ChecklistNodeModel, number>();
  treeControl: FlatTreeControl<ChecklistNodeModel>;

  treeFlattener: MatTreeFlattener<ChecklistNodeModel, ChecklistNodeModel>;

  dataSource: MatTreeFlatDataSource<ChecklistNodeModel, ChecklistNodeModel>;

  constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.treeFlattener = new MatTreeFlattener(this.transformer, this.getLevel,
      this.isExpandable, this.getChildren);
    this.treeControl = new FlatTreeControl<ChecklistNodeModel>(
      this.getLevel, this.isExpandable);
    this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);
    // this.dataSource = new MatTreeFlatDataSource(this.treeControl, this.treeFlattener);
    this.dataSource.data = this.treeData;
  }



  getLevel = (node: ChecklistNodeModel): number => {
    return this.levels.get(node) || 0;
  };

  isExpandable = (node: ChecklistNodeModel): boolean => {
    return node.children.value.length > 0;
  };

  getChildren = (node: ChecklistNodeModel) => {
    return node.children;
  };

  transformer = (node: ChecklistNodeModel, level: number) => {
    this.levels.set(node, level);
    return node;
  }

  hasChildren = (index: number, node: ChecklistNodeModel) => {
    return this.isExpandable(node);
  }

  /** The selection for checklist */
  checklistSelection = new SelectionModel<ChecklistNodeModel>(true /* multiple */);

  /** Whether all the descendants of the node are selected */
  descendantsAllSelected(node: ChecklistNodeModel): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    if (!descendants.length) {
      return this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node);
    }
    const selected = this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node);
    const allSelected = descendants.every(child => this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child));
    if (!selected && allSelected) {
      this.checklistSelection.select(node);
      this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    }
    return allSelected;
  }

  /** Whether part of the descendants are selected */
  descendantsPartiallySelected(node: ChecklistNodeModel): boolean {
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    if (!descendants.length) {
      return false;
    }
    const result = descendants.some(child => this.checklistSelection.isSelected(child));
    return result && !this.descendantsAllSelected(node);
  }

  /** Toggle the selection. Select/deselect all the descendants node */
  nodeSelectionToggle(node: ChecklistNodeModel): void {
    node.checked = !node.checked;
    this.checklistSelection.toggle(node);
    const descendants = this.treeControl.getDescendants(node);
    if(this.checklistSelection.isSelected(node)) {
      this.checklistSelection.select(...descendants, node);
      for(let descendant of descendants) {
        this.nodeSelectionToggle(descendant);
      }
    } else {
      this.checklistSelection.deselect(...descendants, node);
      for(let descendant of descendants) {
        this.nodeSelectionToggle(descendant);
      }
    }
    this.changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.data = this.treeData;
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.dataSource.data = changes.treeData.currentValue;
  }


}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of the child component ?

Comment: @RanikaNisal yes. please check

Comment: So two questions: (1) Is the code that sets TREE_DATA in the parent being reached? (2) Have you tried putting ‘ngOnChanges(changes) { console.log(changes) }’ or something similar in the child?

Comment: Do you get a simpleChanges object when you run the web app?

Comment: @EthanMelamed thanks for your responce. (1) yes it does updates TREE_DATA in parent as far as I can see from Augury. (2) nothing being outputed into logs

Comment: @RanikaNisal looks to me I'm not hitting ngOnChages() at all...

Comment: Have you considered manually triggering the detection using @ViewChild in the parent component and a method to change the treeData in the Child component

Comment: @RanikaNisal can you give a hint please?

Comment: And also @RanikaNisal will I bind it back (changes from child will update parent also)

Comment: If that functionality already existed adding @ViewChild won't remove it. But it won't certainly add it either if it didn't work earlier. However if that is what you need you can also consider using an external service

Comment: @RanikaNisal can you give me a clue how to use ViewChild to pass updated tree to child component, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this in the parent component

```
//import CheckListTreeComponent
//Import viewChild from angular core
export class ParentClass {
      @ViewChild(ChecklistTreeComponent)
      private tree : ChecklistTreeComponent;

      constructor(){}
      //
}
```

At the point you are sure that the parent component has received it's value

```
this.tree.update(this.TREE_DATA)
```

In the child component

```
update(value){
     this.treeData = value;
}
```